# xpath parsing multiple values in a single call

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How do you get xPath value for more than one path in a single call.

for example

```
<Message version="010" release="006"  xmlns="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
</Header>
<Body>
    <CommunicationNumbers>
        <Communication>
            <Number>5551234444</Number>
            <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
        </Communication>
        <Communication>
            <Number>5551235555</Number>
            <Qualifier>FX</Qualifier>
        </Communication>
    </CommunicationNumbers>
    <Identification>
        <FileID>616</FileID>
        <DEANumber>AB123456</DEANumber>
        <SocialSecurity>123456789</SocialSecurity>
    </Identification>
    <Specialty>A</Specialty>
    <ClinicName>Therapy Department</ClinicName>
    <Name>
        <LastName>Xavior</LastName>
        <FirstName>Charles</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>C</MiddleName>
        <Suffix>MD</Suffix>
    </Name>
    <Address>
        <AddressLine1>888 ABC Drive</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>Suite 200</AddressLine2>
        <City>Miami</City>
        <State>FL</State>
        <ZipCode>12345</ZipCode>
    </Address>
</Body>
```

and I need values for :

:Communication/Number
:Identification/FileID
:Specialty

in a single call.

For a single value I am using

```
 public static String getExpValue(final String xmlString, final String expression, final ServiceNamespaceContext nameSpace) throws XPathExpressionException {
    StringReader strReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
    InputSource inputStr = new InputSource(strReader);
    String result = null;
    try {
        final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(nameSpace);

        final XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression);
        result = (String) expr.evaluate(inputStr, XPathConstants.STRING);
    } finally {
        strReader = null;
        inputStr = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My desired output is a single concatenated String 5551234444616A

Answer (score 5):

You could try using something like...

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Communication/Number | //Identification/FileID");
```

Which should combine the results of each query.  In my (simply) test, I got 3 matches (2 for `Communication/Number` and 1 for `Identification/FileID`)

**Updated**

The intended result was to return a `NodeList`, for example...

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(inputStr, XPathConstants.NODELIST);
for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nl.item(index);
    String value = node.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: using this only returns the value of last xpath expression that is //Identification/FileID value 616 it does not concatenate and return 5551234444616

Comment: Sorry, I used it to return `NodeList`

Comment: In my test, it returned the first match.  I don't think `STRING` is capable of doing what you trying to do...

Comment: So nodelist will have all the values ?? and I can iterate the list and get individual values ?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more efficient way of reading multiple xPath values in one call ?

Comment: What do you mean by efficient?

Comment: `XPathConstants.NODELIST` does not look OK anymore, should be `NODESET`. See - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html

Comment: @takias It was 2014 :P

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 the NodeList is replaced by NodeSet:

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(inputStr, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nl.item(index);
    String value = node.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```